# Calling Graph API from Console Application using a User Credentials

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm using following code to call Microsoft Graph API:

```cs
private static void GraphAPICallTest()
{
    try
    {
        string authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token";
        string resrouce = "https://graph.microsoft.com";
        string clientId = "{clientid}";
        string userName = "userid@test.com";
        string password = "{userpassword}";

        UserPasswordCredential userPasswordCredential = new UserPasswordCredential(userName, password);
        AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
        var result = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resrouce, clientId, userPasswordCredential).Result;
        var graphserviceClient = new GraphServiceClient(
            new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
                (requestMessage) =>
                {
                    var access_token = authContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(resrouce, clientId).Result.AccessToken;
                    requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", access_token);
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                }));

        var a = graphserviceClient.Me.Request().GetAsync().Result;
        Console.WriteLine("Success");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex}");
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

When I use any user from Azure AD this code works just fine. but if i use personnel account it errors out with following error.

> ADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID 'c15fd791-7a49-424b-a938-2a9464476277' named 'OneDriveWebAppTest'. Send an interactive authorization request for this user and resource.
>   Trace ID: 5f31be27-dfdd-410b-af41-e769b2573d00
>   Correlation ID: 9c8c9f60-c56d-4845-a223-37f5232c6210
>   Timestamp: 2017-12-11 13:58:39Z

Yes, error is asking about consenting with that personnel user. But even after doing the consent with that user, the error still persist.

Not sure if i'm missing anything.

Comment: To clarify, have you gone through _both Admin Consent and User Consent?

Comment: Only User consent. My application doesn't use any application level permission that requires admin consent. It uses only delegated permission. so I did only User consent. I don't want to force the requirement for Admin consent unless it is must.

Comment: Which scopes did you select?

Comment: For the "personal account" are you trying to sign in and get the profile of the Microsoft Account (signed-in user) OR is this user using that Microsoft Account to sign in to the AAD tenant (as a guest user)?

Comment: I am trying to access one drive of logged in user . User is microsoft account. Not associated with aad and not a guest user.